# Different outputs for Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, system

In at least one instance, the same `Simplify` command (without using options) produces very different results on two of my computers, one Windows 7 and the other Windows 10. Here is the code:

```
sf = Simplify;

r1 = (-1 + (-11 - a^2 + 2 a^4) b^2 + (8 - 3 a^2) b^3 + (-2 + a^2) b^4 - 
     b (-6 - 3 a^2 + a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        2 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
     a (Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 3 Sqrt[b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + Sqrt[
        b^7 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]))/(-1 + b - a^2 b + 
     a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^2;
```

This is what I got on one of the computers, the Windows 10 one:

```
Dr1 = D[r1, b] // sf 

(* (6 + 3 a^2 + 2 (-11 - a^2 + 2 a^4) b + 3 (8 - 3 a^2) b^2 + 
    4 (-2 + a^2) b^3 - (a (1 + (-2 + a^2) b))/Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - (
    a b (1 + (-2 + a^2) b))/Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - (
    2 a^3 b (1 + (-2 + a^2) b))/Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 
    a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 2 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + (
    a b^6 (-7 - 4 (-2 + a^2) b))/Sqrt[b^7 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + (
    3 a b^4 (5 + 3 (-2 + a^2) b))/Sqrt[b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])/(-1 + b - 
    a^2 b + a Sqrt[
     b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^2 - (2 (1 - a^2 + (a - 2 a b + a^3 b)/Sqrt[
      b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) (-1 + (-11 - a^2 + 2 a^4) b^2 + (8 - 
         3 a^2) b^3 + (-2 + a^2) b^4 - 
      b (-6 - 3 a^2 + a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
         2 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
      a (Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 3 Sqrt[b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + Sqrt[
         b^7 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])))/(-1 + b - a^2 b + 
    a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^3 *)
```

And this, much better expression is what I got on the other computer, the Windows 7 one:

```
D[r1, b] // sf

(* (2 (-1 + b)^2 b (4 (-2 + 9 a^2 - 8 a^4 + 2 a^6) b^4 - 
     3 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 
     b (-8 - 11 a^2 + 10 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        10 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
     b^2 (24 - 14 a^2 - 14 a^4 - 29 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        14 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        4 a^5 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
     b^3 (-24 + 61 a^2 - 18 a^4 - 4 a^6 + 16 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 
        24 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        8 a^5 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])))/(Sqrt[
   b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] (-a b + Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^3 (-1 + b - 
     a^2 b + a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^2) *)
```

Can I find the reason for this and make it the same on both computers? If so, how to do this? I may have changed global preferences for `Simplify` on the Windows 7 computer, but don't remember if or how or what I did concerning that. This behavior occurs both in Mathematica 11.2 and Mathematica 11.1.1.

Comment: `Simplify` is time constrained. Consequently, you get the best result that is found within that time. Since different machines provide different performance, you can get different results. You can use the option `TimeConstraint` to go beyond the default: `Options[Simplify, TimeConstraint]`

Comment: @BobHanlon : Thank you for your comment. I have now tried it with TimeConstraint -> \[Infinity] on the Windows 10 computer, but the result is the same bad expression.

Comment: I get your results on a Mac that are identical to your Windows10 results. Does `$Assumptions` for either system contain any assumptions on `a` or `b`?

Comment: @BobHanlon : Thank you for checking it on your Mac and making the comment. On my Windows 7 machine, I used `$Assumptions = (a > 0 && 0 < b < 1)`. When I use the same  `$Assumptions` on the Windows 10 computer, the output changes just a bit, but it is just as bad and unusable as without the `$Assumptions`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better form, use [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
$Assumptions = a > 0 && 0 < b < 1; 
(* from your comment *)

r1 = (-1 + (-11 - a^2 + 2 a^4) b^2 + (8 - 3 a^2) b^3 + (-2 + a^2) b^4 - 
     b (-6 - 3 a^2 + a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        2 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
     a (Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 3 Sqrt[b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        Sqrt[b^7 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]))/(-1 + b - a^2 b + 
      a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^2;

Dr1 = D[r1, b] // FullSimplify

(* ((-1 + b)^2 (2 a^5 b^2 (1 + 2 b) + 3 a (-1 + b)^2 (1 + 4 b) + 
     2 a^3 b (3 + (4 - 7 b) b) - 
     2 a^2 (2 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 3 Sqrt[b^3 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 
        5 Sqrt[b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
     4 (Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 2 Sqrt[b^3 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + Sqrt[
        b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
     2 a^4 (Sqrt[b^3 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
        2 Sqrt[b^5 (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])))/(Sqrt[
   b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] (-1 + b - a^2 b + a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^3) *)

Dr1 // LeafCount

(* 248 *)
```

Whereas the `LeafCount` for your Windows 7 result with `Simplify` is `317`

```
(2 (-1 + b)^2 b (4 (-2 + 9 a^2 - 8 a^4 + 2 a^6) b^4 - 
      3 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 
      b (-8 - 11 a^2 + 10 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
         10 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
      b^2 (24 - 14 a^2 - 14 a^4 - 29 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
         14 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
         4 a^5 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)]) - 
      b^3 (-24 + 61 a^2 - 18 a^4 - 4 a^6 + 16 a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] - 
         24 a^3 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] + 
         8 a^5 Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])))/(Sqrt[
     b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)] (-a b + Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^3 (-1 + b - 
       a^2 b + a Sqrt[b (2 + (-2 + a^2) b)])^2) // LeafCount

(* 317 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I get about the same `LeafCount` (251) by first (manually) collecting the `Sqrt` terms in the expression for `r1` and then using the simple `Simplify` on `D[r1,b]`, and I get your leaf count 248 using `FullSimplify` on `D[r1,b]`. However, my befuddlement at the very different outputs of the same command on different computers still remains.