# Incomplete plot problem

Tags: plotting, graphics, evaluation, hold

I have this code:

```
In[1]:= H[u_] = 
  1/2 ((-2 + Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])]) Log[
       1 - 1/2 Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])]] - (Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])] - 
        Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])]) Log[
       1/2 (Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])] - 
          Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])])] - (Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])] - 
        Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])]) Log[
       1/2 (Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])] - Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])])] - 
     Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])] Log[1/2 Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])]]);

In[2]:= H[2.1] // Log10 // N[#, 10] &

Out[2]= Indeterminate

In[3]:= H[Rationalize[2.1, 10^-10]] // Log10 // N[#, 10] &

Out[3]= -1.047657131
```

However, when I do

```
In[4]:= Plot[(H[Rationalize[u, 10^-10]] // Log10 // N[#, 10] &) // 
  Evaluate, {u, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get an incomplete plot; the values of the function for u>1.7 (or so) are apparently left unevaluated:

```
Out[4]=
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Use `H[u_] :=` rather than `H[u_] =` and things should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) option in [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
H[u_] = 1/2 ((-2 + Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])]) Log[
       1 - 1/2 Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])]] - (Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])] - 
        Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])]) Log[1/2 (Erfc[-((5 u)/Sqrt[2])] - 
          Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])])] - (Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])] - 
        Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])]) Log[
       1/2 (Erfc[-((3 u)/Sqrt[2])] - Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])])] - 
     Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])] Log[1/2 Erfc[-(u/Sqrt[2])]]);

Plot[H[u] // Log10, {u, 0, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. A crazy thing is that this works on a Windows 10 computer, but not on Windows 7 one! Cf. the opposite kind of situation described at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165423/different-outputs-for-simplify . Can anyone explain these crazy things?

Comment: @IosifPinelis - what version of Mathematica are you running in each case? If both are the current version (11.2), report it to Wolfram support.

Comment: @IosifPinelis - if part of the plot is missing it is may be due to imaginary artifacts from precision issues. Since you know that the function is real in the range of interest, try plotting `Re[H[u]//Log10]` or `H[u]//Log10//Chop` with Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you for your additional, helpful comments as well.